# How to get motherboard type in C?

Tags: c, windows, hardware

I want to create a small application which gets my motherboards type. How can i do this using C?

Thanks, kampi

Comment: I don't know of a `motherboard` type in C. Is it in some windows header or something?

Comment: Pop off the cover and take a look.  That's as close as you are going to get, the WMI queries rarely work.

Comment: @Hans: the reason why i want to create such an apllication is because, i want to create an universal image, and i need for this such an application. So popping of the cover, isn't a solution. And i don't want to use WMI.

Comment: What the heck is a 'universal image'?  A camera still requires you to pop the cover.  You have to point it up to get the universe.

Comment: A universal image is for example a ghost image, which contains, many drivers for many motherboards....

Answer (score 2):

You could get the information you want with [GetSystemFirmwareTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724379%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 System Call. Not sure if you will find the exact information you are looking for though. Check out the doc.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, but as i can see, the minimum requirement for this function is XP x64, but i'm using XP Professioanal x86 :(